# Laravel - Unique Validation with multiple columns and not equal to

Tags: validation, laravel, unique

I need to validate two inputs, title and status. In my a raw query that would be

`WHERE title = ? AND status != 'DELETED'`

How do I do that in Laravel's validation
Here's my code:

```
'adName'=> 'required|max:150|unique:adstable,title,'.Input::get('ad-name'),
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are only two built in "database" validation rules - `unique` and `distinct`.

I would extend the validator with a custom validation rule:

```
Validator::extend('undeletedTitle', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    // insert your rules here
});
```

I would also argue this is clearer/cleaner than trying to fit some quite complex logic into a pipe separated string.

[More custom validation rules information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)